# change jquery need to be tap twice?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I try to kind of combine the experience of 2 drop down (date and time) into one to produce better UX. Don't ask me why I don't use html5 datetime, it's because I'm doing a fallback for older phone here.

I want when I tap on the time the date dropdown got trigger, and when the selection of date is done, open the dropdown of time. here is my partial code

```
$('#time').on('focus',function(event){
    openDropDown($('#date'));
});

$("#date").change(function () {
    if(this.value != 0){
        openDropDown($('#time'));
        $('#time').off('focus');
    }
});
```

But why it doesn't work properly? where I need to tap twice for the date dropdown to work properly?

DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/vuz8bpvv/

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

        $('#time').on('focus',function(event){
            openDropDown($('#date'));
        });

        $("#date").change(function () {
            if(this.value != 0){
                $('#time').off('focus'); // first, focus the time drop down
                openDropDown($('#time'));
            }
        });

        function openDropDown(elem) {
        if (document.createEvent) {
            var e = document.createEvent("MouseEvents");
            e.initMouseEvent("mousedown", true, true, window, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, false, false, false, false, 0, null);
            elem[0].dispatchEvent(e);
        } else if (element.fireEvent) {
            elem[0].fireEvent("onmousedown");
        }
    }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="date">
    <option value="0">Date</option>
    <option>3/4/2015</option>
    <option>4/4/2015</option>
    <option>5/4/2015</option>
</select>
<select id="time">
    <option>Time</option>
    <option>1:00 AM</option>
    <option>2:00 AM</option>
</select>
```